# Amazon family / household - how to sign child in?

Tags: amazon

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but how do I sign a child in to their account under Amazon family?  I added them under my account and shared Audible content with them but I don't see a way to sign them in.  Searching online doesn't turn up anything so I'm guessing this is intuitive to others =).